# schedule method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can i send emails automatically every day by asp.net application and c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a Scheduler like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). It will give you the most precise, flexible, and predictable results.

Comment: Or if they want to write themselves, could put together a simple windows service to do it.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET application cannot run scheduled code. It works on simple request response pattern so it can run the code only if HTTP request arrives. To do the scheduling you have to write another application. Ugly way is to use console application and schedule it by Windows scheduler. Better approach is to use windows service.